# Generate a js library using typescipt

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I want to create a JavaScript library using TypeScript.
After bundling I would like to have:

- one file
- only functions which are exported in root file are accessible
- functionality

But if I use webpack I don't get it how I can access my exported function.

my code:

```js
export function test(){
console.log("testcase2 succeeded");
}
```

my webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');



const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');



module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'test',
        libraryTarget:"umd"
    },

    plugins: [new webpack.ProgressPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],

                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            {
                                modules: false
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    priority: -10,
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                }
            },

            chunks: 'async',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 30000,
            name: true
        }
    },

    devServer: {
        open: true
    }
};
```

result of webpack:

```js
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["test"] = factory();
    else
        root["test"] = factory();
})(window, function() {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/index.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./src/index.js":
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./src/index.js ***!
  \**********************/
/*! exports provided: test */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"test\", function() { return test; });\nfunction test() {\n  console.log(\"Hello World from your main file!\");\n}\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://test/./src/index.js?");

/***/ })

/******/ });
});
```

If I use other like gulp:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compile', function() {
     var tsResult = gulp.src('./src/outer1.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // This means sourcemaps will be generated 
        .pipe(ts({
                       // ... 
         }));

      return tsResult
         .pipe(concat('lib/js-library.js')) // You can use other plugins that also support gulp-sourcemaps
        //  .pipe(uglify()) 
         .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // Now the sourcemaps are added to the .js file 
         .pipe(gulp.dest('release/'));
});
```

I have the problem, that `require("./inner1")` woukd work:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var inner1_1 = require("./inner1");
function outer1() {
    console.log("outer1");
    inner1_1.inner1();
}
exports.outer1 = outer1;
```

Comment: In part, webpack defaults to 'development' mode, rather than production - if you set the mode to 'production' then that will remove some of the superfluous code. https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/